# Modificar intervalos de obs de variable, acorde a dummies de otras dos variables. DF. for

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en python. Mi data es la siguiente (DataFrame):

```
 var1 var2 var3
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 -1      0  -1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
  0      1   1
  0      0   1
 ...    ... ...
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 -1      0  -1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 ...    ... ...
```

A lo que necesito llegar es a:

```
 var1 var2 var3
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 -1      0  -1
  0      0  -1
  0      0  -1
  0      1   1
  0      0   1
 ...    ... ...
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 -1      0  -1
  0      0  -1
  0      0  -1
 ...    ... ...
```

Es decir, que después de la `Dummy` negativa en la columna `var1`, me cambia las siguientes obs de signo hasta encontrar otra `dummy` positiva en la columna `var2` y así sucesivamente... lo intenté hacer con un `for` pero no termina nunca de ejecutarse. No se si habrá alguna otra forma?

```
for x, y in enumerate(df['var3']):
    if (df['var3'][x]!=df['var3'][x-1]) and (df['var1'][x+1]==df['var2'][x+1]):
        df['var3'][x]=df['var3'][x]*-1
    else:
        df['var3'][x]=df['var3'][x]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin asumir nada, tal como planteas el problema, se puede resolver usando simplemente condicionales y una variable bandera que indique cuando estamos dentro de un intervalo en el que debemos invertir el signo de la tercera columna (entre un valor negativo en la primera columna y el siguiente positivo en la segunda):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
var1 var2 var3
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 -1      0  -1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
  0      1   1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1
 -1      0  -1
  0      0   1
  0      0   1    
  0      1   1
  0      0   1
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")


cambiar_signo = False
for idx in df.index:
    if cambiar_signo:
        if df.loc[idx, "var2"] > 0:
            cambiar_signo = False
        else:
            df.loc[idx, "var3"] *= -1
    else:
        if df.loc[idx, "var1"] < 0:
            cambiar_signo = True
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>
>     var1  var2  var3
> 0      0     0     1
> 1      0     0     1
> 2      0     0     1
> 3     -1     0    -1
> 4      0     0    -1
> 5      0     0    -1
> 6      0     1     1
> 7      0     0     1
> 8      0     0     1
> 9      0     0     1
> 10    -1     0    -1
> 11     0     0    -1
> 12     0     0    -1
> 13     0     1     1
> 14     0     0     1
> ```

Si asumimos que la secuencia es siempre tal como se muestra en el ejemplo de la pregunta (negativo en `var1` seguido de positivo en `var2`), es decir que no se dan situaciones como:

```
var1  var2
  1      0  # <<< Valor positivo en valor1
 -1      0 
  0      0 
 -1      0  # <<< Dos valores negativos sin intercalar positivo en var2
  0      1

var1  var2
  0      0 
  0      1  # <<< Valor positivo en var2 sin que le preceda uno negativo en var1
 -1      0 
  0      0
  0      1

var1  var2
  0      0 
 -1      0 
  0     -1  # <<< Valor negativo en var2
  0      0
  0      1
```

En este supuesto, podemos simplificar la cosa y vectorizar la operación usando una suma acumulativa por ejemplo:

```
aux = (df['var1'] + df['var2']).cumsum()
aux.loc[df["var1"] < 0] = False # La fila donde var1 tiene valor negativo no se cambia
df.loc[aux != 0, "var3"] *= -1
```

No importaría que los valores de las columnas `var1` y `var2` fueran distintos de 1 ó -1, en tal caso bastaría con usar `numpy.sing` previamente sobre ellas:

```
aux = (np.sign(df['var1']) + np.sign(df['var2'])).cumsum()
aux.loc[df["var1"] < 0] = False
df.loc[aux != 0, "var3"] *= -1
```

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla! Justo lo que necesitaba.